# How to purge eXist-db from Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: purge

I've uninstalled eXists-db (through the uninstall.jar file) and the system tray icon keeps appearing when switching work spaces. How can I purge any remains of the program?

Comment: Did you restart the system?

Comment: Yes and it's still there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the remnants look in two places:

1. `/usr/share/applications` and
2. `/home/$USER/.local/share/applications`

Look for the `.desktop` file for that program and simply delete them. After that re-start your system.

Comment: The second option worked, there were eXists files still there. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked, cheers!

Comment: After uninstall version 3.4.1 and installing version 3.3.0 it seems that the service of the "old" version still exists, because the server couldn't be started. How can I check if the service is uninstalled too?